# How could i turn a Map() into a string as it is, WITHOUT it becoming a json object in js/ts

Tags: javascript, string, dictionary

Basically i want to turn a Map into a string as text. I have tried `toString()` and template literals but those return [object Map] obviously. I also saw that some people converted the Map into an object then called `JSON.stringify()` on it.

However i don't want my Map be displayed as a JSON Object, but as an actual Map

Suppose i had a Map of

```js
{ 'key' => 'value' }
```

i want it to be displayed like the above and not like the one below

```js
{
  "key": "value"
}
```

Is there any way i could achieve this?

UPDATE:
After some experimenting i finally found a alright-enough method

```js
const convertMapToString = (m: Map<string, IGuildCache | object>) => {

    let mapEntries = [...m.keys()]

    return '{\n' + mapEntries.map(k => {
        return '    ' + k + ' => ' + JSON.stringify(m.get(k), null, 2)
    }).join(',\n') + '\n}'
}
```

The values of the map were objects so i did not mind converting them into JSON.

Comment: What do you mean with display? there is no kind of displaying an object as a string in general.

Comment: Yes there's a way to achieve it: decide on what your Map should look like as a string, and then write your own code to make it look that way. Converting a Map instance to a string via a process involving `JSON.stringify()` is going to be difficult in the general case, because JSON syntax only allows string keys.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you need to display object like { 'key' => 'value' } and not ":" exists on key or value you can do

```
let data = {'key' : 'value'}
JSON.stringify(data).replace(":", " => ")
```

Comment: this will not work if any keys or values contain a colon

Answer (score 0):

You'l have to create your own functions, maybe something like :

```
function displayMapsWithCustomFormat(m: Map) {

  let asStrings = m.map((key, value) => `"${key}" => "${value}"`);
  console.log("{\n" + asStrings.join(",\n") + "}");
}
```

Not tested, but you can give it a try. You can complexify a bit if you espext other types. Like if you have nested map, make this function recursive.